# Does flash memory ever change on execution?

Tags: embedded, flash-memory

I'm required to do a code verification using CRC. In this case, all I do is pass every byte found flash memory through an algorithm to calculate the CRC and compare the result to a predefined CRC value.

However, I'm hung up on the idea that the flash memory might change at some point, causing the CRC verification to fail.

Assuming that the code isn't touched again whatsoever, is it possible that flash memory will change during execution? If so, what can cause it to change? And how do I avoid said change?

Comment: You don't say if it's NAND or NOR flash.  Primary failure mode for NOR flash is that a cell either fails to erase or it fails to write.  So long as the data in NOR flash is only read, it should remain intact for some time.  Check your data sheet for retention times.  In addition to write and erase failures, NAND flash is subject to read disturb.  That is, reading a cell can cause changes to other nearby cells.  Proper use of NAND flash requires ECC.

Comment: The whole point of adding a CRC is to detect when the flash memory goes corrupt. CRC is the preferred algorithm since it is good at detecting errors in the checksum itself, as well as in the data. With a large enough polynomial, you will detect all single-bit errors and most multi-bit errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flash memory only means it retains its content in the absence of power; flash memory is definitely erasable / reprogrammable. The separate term Read-Only-Memory (ROM) means it cannot be altered after the initial write.

But memory doesn't change unless a CPU instruction touches it or it degrades or is affected by external factors. Flash memory contents might last ten years unperturbed. Usually it is the number of read/write cycles that degrade flash memory before age does. High static electrical charges could corrupt flash but magnetic fields should have little effect.

If you have any influence over the hardware specs, ROM should be considered if that is the primary intent; it has several advantages over flash for this purpose.

Lastly, you note that you will pass *"every byte"* of memory through your CRC algorithm. If the correct checksum is to be stored within the same memory medium, you have a recursive problem of trying to precompute a checksum that contains it's own checksum. In most cases, the valid checksum should be located in some segment of the memory that is not itself subjected to the scan.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! You're right, I didn't even think of that. If I try to predefine the correct checksum, It'll be stored in flash memory as well right? That would change the checksum done at run time -.-

Comment: @RCRod21 You're welcome, please remember to accept the answer when you get a chance.

Comment: If you have a product that lives longer than the data retention specification, then flash memory will always fail, at some point.

Answer (score 0):

In any event if it *were* to change spontaneously that is exactly what your code verification is intended to catch and you would want and expect the CRC to fail, so there is no problem - it is doing its job

It is mostly not a matter of spontaneously changing, but rather one of not being written correctly in the first instance, or possibly protecting against malicious or accidental tampering. If part of the flash is used for variable non-volatile storage, you would obviously not include that area in your CRC.  If you *are* partitioning the same flash into code space and NV storage, potentially errors in the NV storage code could inadvertently modify the code space, so your CRC protects against that and also external tampering (via JTAG for example).

Flash memory is subject to erase/write cycle endurance, and after a number of cycles some bits may stick "high".  Endurance varies between parts from around 10000 to 100000, and is seldom a problem for code storage. Flash memory also has a nominal data retention time; this is normally quoted at 10 years; but that is worst-case extreme condition rating - again your CRC guards against these effects.